# OOP: inheritance with recursive class definition

Tags: java, class, oop, inheritance, recursion

I have (*recursively*) defined a class for implementing a binary tree (in Java):

```
class BinaryTree {
    protected int key;
    protected BinaryTree left, right;

    // some methods...
}
```

from which I want to implement a binary *search* tree, like this:

```
class BinarySearchTree extends BinaryTree {
    // ...

    public BinarySearchTree search(int x) {
        if (x == key)
            return this;
        if (x < key)
            if (left != null)
                return left.search(x);  // (*)
        else
            if (right != null)
                return right.search(x); // (*)
        return null;
    }
}
```

but of course the lines marked with `// (*)` won't compile beacause `left` and `right` are just `BinaryTree`s, without any `search()` method.

So I am wondering if theres is a way to define `BinarySearchTree` from the `BinaryTree` superclass **but** with `left` and `right` being actually `BinarySearchTree`s.

Or maybe there is a better way of implementing the relationship between binary trees and the *search* ones: should I define a separate `Node` class? should I use templates? should I avoid recursive definitions at all? ...

Comment: What's the point in having two seperate classes here? Why not just put the search() method in BinaryTree and forget about BinarySearchTree?

Comment: Yes, but allowing a `search()` method inside a binary tree which is not organized as a binary *search* tree would be "dangerous“ because the method can become computationally intractable when the tree grows: the `BinaryTree` search would be brute-force, while the `BinarySearchTree` is guaranteed to be at most logarithmic. But this is more about algorithms and data structures than about OOP :)

Comment: A possibly cleaner design than the generics solution would be to make the binary tree an interface and make a plain binary tree implementation as well as a binary search tree.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use recursive generics.

Define a recursive generic type variable, say, `B`:

```
class BinaryTree<B extends BinaryTree<B>> {
```

and make your fields of this type:

```
protected B left, right;
```

Then define:

```
class BinarySearchTree extends BinaryTree<BinarySearchTree> {
```

Now `left` and `right` are of type `BinarySearchTree` too, allowing you to call `left.search` and `right.search`.

Comment: I didn't know about generics (I just shifted from C++ two months ago) but your solution is probably just what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: The only downside of this I can see is that for plain `BinaryTree`s, you'll have to type the slightly verbose `BinaryTree<BinaryTree>`.

Comment: @qxz that'd be a raw type. Yep, it's rather ugly.

Comment: Oh gosh you're right... Is it even possible to give a non-raw type parameter?

Comment: @qxz erm not sure. I mostly try to avoid recursive generics. Probably with a type variable. Or, make the `BinaryTree` class abstract, and never deal with that type directly.

Answer (score 1):

I feel `BinaryTreeNode` should be created as an inner class of`BinaryTree.java`. BinaryTreeNode can have `int data`, and two references of type `BinaryTreeNode` for `left` and `right` node

`BinaryTree.java` should have an reference of type `BinaryTreeNode` which will be the root of the tree.

Now `BinarySearchTree extends BinaryTree` looks good, you can include an method in it as below signature.

```
BinaryTreeNode `search( int k, BinaryTreeNode root)`
```

**Now you can define the recursive method.**

Please see Sample code with basic skeleton.

**BinaryTreeNode.java**

```
public class BinaryTreeNode {

    private int data;
    private BinaryTreeNode left, right;

    public BinaryTreeNode(int data) {
        this.setData(data);
    }

    public BinaryTreeNode getLeft() {
        return left;
    }

    public void setLeft(BinaryTreeNode left) {
        this.left = left;
    }

    public BinaryTreeNode getRight() {
        return right;
    }

    public void setRight(BinaryTreeNode right) {
        this.right = right;
    }

    public int getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(int data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

}
```

**BinaryTree.java**

```
public class BinaryTree {
    protected BinaryTreeNode root;

    // other basic methods needed for creating the Binary tree.
}
```

**BinarySearchTree.java**

```
public class BinarySearchTree extends BinaryTree {
    public BinaryTreeNode search(int k) {
        return search(k, root);
    }

    private BinaryTreeNode search(int k, BinaryTreeNode root) {
        if (root.getData() == k) {
            return root;
        }
        if (root.getData() < k) {
            return search(k, root.getRight());
        } else {
            return search(k, root.getLeft());
        }
    }
    // add other methods needed for creating the Binary search tree.
    // also override the methods which needs to be modified for their behavior
    // for binary search tree
}
```

Comment: But wait: being `BinaryTreeNode`s, `left` and `right` don't have any `search()` method, right?

Comment: @George, BinaryTreeNode does not has search method. It is the BinarySearchTree extends BinaryTree which will contain the search method. BinaryTree contains the reference to an object of BinaryTreeNode.

Comment: Oh now I see: so I would have to call `search(x, left);`. Ok, I guess this would work too, thanks!

Comment: @George, wait let me put the actual code in my answer, hope it will be helpful in clearing what I mean

Comment: I have added the basic code, hopefully it will be helpful